# Django auth + userena + django_facebook from another database

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-facebook

I have a Django installation with userena and django_facebook working pretty fine. Can I somewhat make my authentication work from another database (one database for authentication and another for everything else)? The problem is that the project I'm working on requires the same authentication across different Django installations on servers with one entire server for the databases. Should I make a database router that handles all the apps or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple database routers solved the problem with regular Django authentication and Userena authentication. I'm guessing it will be the same with Facebook as they are chained together. The only downfall is that the user for the admin panel is the same across all sites.

Answer (score 0):

Authentication backends are what you are looking for. Django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#other-authentication-sources

Comment: Yes, but that's when you don't already have an authentication backend. I already have three (standart django.contrib.auth for the admin, userena for the site and django facebook). Is it a wise idea to chain them somehow in one global auth backend and "point" it to a different database or just make a database router for all the auth apps?